# Forest portals in the context of GIS and maps

Tags: web-mapping, web-service

Do you know any portals connected with forests and forestry in the context of GIS and maps?
The best for me will be portals where the data is served via WMS, WFS or WCS services.
The only portals i know are from Poland:

[Regional Directorate of State Forests in Krakov](http://rdlpkrakow.gis-net.pl/)

[Regional Directorate of State Forests in Zielona Góra](http://rdlpzg.gis-net.pl/)

I found a new one- it is the [map of nature conservation in the forests of north-eastern Polish](http://mapa.bialystok.lasy.gov.pl/)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Norway: http://www.skogoglandskap.no/temaer/WMS 
is the catalogue of the Norwegian Forest and Landscape Institute.

You can find the provided W*S services (also from other partners of Norway Digital) also by searching http://www.geonorge.no - (for example for 'skog' - forest)

The catalogues are not internationalized yet, unfortunately.

Answer (score 7):

Forestry is really big here in BC, and there are lots of resources available.

A good site is the one published by GeoBC:

http://geobc.gov.bc.ca/

Going through "Content By Sector", "Natural Resources & Economic Development" and finally "Forest, Grasslands and Wetlands" provides a long list of resources.

For WMS services, there's a list of those too:

http://archive.ilmb.gov.bc.ca/dm/wms/index.html

Answer (score 3):

See also the [European FOREST Action website](http://forest.jrc.ec.europa.eu/).

Answer (score 1):

The Victorian state government (in Australia) Department of Sustainability and Environment (DSE) offers a bunch of interactive [web maps](http://www.dse.vic.gov.au/dse/dsencor.nsf/LinkView/836EE128E54D861FCA256DA200208B945FD09CE028D6AA58CA256DAC0029FA1A), including the Forest Explorer Online.

The Forest Explorer is a viewer only unfortunately. However if you log onto the [Biodiversity Interactive Map](http://mapshare2.dse.vic.gov.au/MapShare2EXT/imf.jsp?site=bim), register with DSE and login you can download some of the data.

As far as I know these maps use WMS/WFS feeds, but I think you'd have to enquire with DSE as to whether you could grab those feeds.